# Do we need to define Option(Maybe) in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-generics

In the context of Functional Programming, I want to have the capabilities of Option or Maybe from Scala, Haskell in TypeScript.

I can simply define `Option` below with TS compiler option **strictNullChecks** turned on:

```
type Option<A> = A | null
```

While in Haskell, PureScript, ... it is defined like

```
type Option<A> = Some<A> | None
type Maybe<A> = Just<A> | Nothing
```

In order to benefit from the concept, Do I have to wrap my value in Some or Just and define a separate Symbol for null, or is what I typed above is enough?

Comment: Take the type `Option<null>`. With the proper definition, you can distinguish between the value `Some(null)` and `None`, with yours you cannot. It's not a proper [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) it its utility depends on what type you pass in.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Thank you @Bergi

Comment: This really depends on use cases.  Haskell has disjoint unions, while TypeScript has more general unions, and disjoint unions need to be [built](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  If you want to exactly emulate `Maybe` then you should build a discriminated union like `type Maybe<T> = Just<T> | Nothing; type Just<T> = {type: "Just", value: T}; type Nothing = {type: "Nothing"}`. But most use cases don't actually require this, and it's clunkier to use than just `T | null`.  What are your use cases?

Comment: (That said, you can still go a long way with this until you run into trouble, as one normally does not use `Option<null>` and only rarely an `Option<… | null>`, so it's still a useful definition especially as `type Option<A extends {}>`, but it's just a way of dealing with `null` values not defining a separate data type as in functional programming)

Comment: @jcalz I don't have a specific use-case. Just trying to understand the concept better. What Bergi mentioned on the top make sense to me. I'm not trying to emulate Maybe but define it as we expect the concept from Functional Programming and not language specific. Trying to see what am I missing by not wrapping the value in typescript, and not defining a Symbol for null.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, but if we try to think of it as Math and soundness, It seems that we need to wrap the value. Unless we reserve `null` value in our applications specifically for the "absence of the value".

Comment: Look up tagged unions and structural vs nominaln typing. Silvio Mayolo had a great answer on some other question that made tagged unions finally click for me, I'm trying (so far unsuccessfully) to find it and link it here.

Comment: Maybe I could answer the question with "if your use case requires distinguishing `Maybe<Maybe<T>>` from `Maybe<T>`, then yes, you need to define a discriminated union, and the wrapping/unwrapping involved in that.  Otherwise you're probably better off just defining it as `T | undefined` (more customary than `null`) because there's less boilerplate.  And I'd show [this implementation](https://tsplay.dev/mZX01w).  Would that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Please just post the answer if you already have it prepared anyway

Comment: @jcalz I agree, that was my take here as well. I think the question reduced to, "Can we consider 'null' as an absent of a value". If yes then we don't need another wrapper. If we even have one case that we need to differentiate (like if Option<null> is a think) then I would say no we don't need an extra wrapper.

Comment: You can utilize `null` to mimick `Option`/`Maybe` without concerns. `Nothing` is a constant value just like `null`. Used as a functor/monad, `null` merely signals short circuition of the current computation. `Either` is different, though. If you mimick it with `Error` (+ subclasses) you are limited to this type in case of `Left`. `Left a` has a type var and is thus more general. It can adapt to any type, not just `Error`. So should the JS implementation of `Either` as a proper ADT. I actually use the more specific variant where `Left` is stuck with `Error` but call it `Exception`.

Comment: I believe it worth consider using `fp-ts` library

Comment: @jcalz Do you have a good example of when we want to distinguish between `Maybe<Maybe<T>>` and `Maybe<T>`? (I know Maybe is a Monadic type and nested Maybes can be flattened, but lets not considering this here)

Comment: I don't know about a "good" example, but all such examples will be the same flavor as "what if `null` is a valid value?"... you have different kinds of `Nothing` and want to distinguish them.  [Here is an example](https://tsplay.dev/w2zMjw) where a `Maybe<Maybe<number>>` represents an optional price of some optional product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define it as

```
type Option<T> = {value: T} | null;
```

This way it does not become ambiguous when `null` is a possible value of type `T` (as pointed out in the comments) and you can use it as follows:

```
if (myValueOfOptionType) {
  console.log(myValueOfOptionType.value);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Yea if all the use-cases of null in our application would be the concept of "absence of the value" then we can pass Option instance around without any issue. But lets say if we use an external library that null has a specific meaning, undefined another, ... then we may have an issue when composing our functions and passing Option around.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, obviously you can't pass values of type `Option<T>` to a function/library that is unaware of it, it wouldn't know what to do with it. So if you want to pass such a value to an external function, you first need to unpack it and deal with the null case somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my question with my findings.

If our initial type already has null value in it, we would have a problem. Take a look at the different paths to return values in the function below. Imagine Integer is a set of all Integer values. Then look into where I used `null` and `just(null)`:

```
function divide2IfEven(x: Integer): Option<Integer | null> {
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    if (x === 0)
      return null
    else
      return just(2 / x)
  } else {
    return just(null)
  }
}
```

Here I am distinguishing between the result of calculation and error. I'm considering divide by zero an illegal operation, but output for odd numbers to be absence of an answer, but not an error.

This is why it is a better to wrap the value in an object like in `Some` or `Just`.

Comment: The underlying problem you try to *patch* is the ambiguous use of `null`. The type should be either used to encode absence of a result or exceptions but not both. It's always better to fix an issue at its root than to patch its impact on your code. The least surprising return type would be `Infinity` because all JS numbers are float and `Infinity` is the type's standard behavior. `just(null)` should be `nothing`. If you are forced to use the former due to code constraints, I'd stick with `null` rather than forcing ADTs.

Comment: After I gave this more thought I believe you are right Iven. This example is a bit stretch. I think what I was trying to demonstrate was what @jcalz mentioned in the comments on the question. The question would be do we want to distinguish between `Maybe<Maybe<A>>` and `Maybe<A>` or not.

Comment: `Maybe<Maybe<A>>` is a nested structure we usually want to avoid. That's why `flatMap`/`bind` etc. exist. What does `Just (Just a)` or `Just Nothing` mean? Monad gives the answer: `Just a` and `Nothing`. Joining two structures of the same type is what determines a monad. If you dig deeper into FP you'll learn about intentionally deferring the monadic joining process, i.e. separating construction from interpretation of structures (free monads). This is when you need `Maybe<Maybe<A>>` to build a tree. But I wouldn't worry about it now.

Comment: Oh that's exactly what I was looking for. I totally agree, if we try to interpret `Just(Just a)` or  `Just Nothing`, we can reduce them to simpler values. But what I'm hearing from you also is, we need to structurally being able to create `Maybe<Maybe<A>>`, although that can be flattened later since `Maybe` is a Monadic type. Is what I said correct and be good reason to the main question? Btw do you have a link that gives an example of `Maybe<Maybe<A>>` you mentioned?